# jQuery - transform selected <option> into specific link

Tags: jquery

I have a list of options for user to choose:

```
<select>
<option>Twitter</option>
<option>Google</option>
</select>
```

After user has selected an option and pressed special button on the page, I need to transform the whole `<select>` list into a link.
For example, if user selects "Google", then the whole `<select>` list is replaced with:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a>
```

If "Twitter" was selected, this will be:

```
<a href="twitter.com">Twitter</a>
```

Comment: I'd also like to have a set of custom links for each option, that differs from the text value. For example, option "Smartphones" but the link's URL is "apple.com". So how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We check if the button is clicked
2. We grab the selected value
3. We replace the `select` with the formed link (using the grabbed value)

If you want to use custom url for the selected option, just add custom value for the option like this:

```
<option value="yahoo.com">This is yahoo</option>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button").click(function () {
        var which = $("select").val();
        var text = $('select option:selected').html();
        $("select").replaceWith("<a href='http://" + which + "'>" + text + "</a>");

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="twitter.com">This is twitter</option>
    <option value="google.com">This is google</option>
</select>
<button>Special button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'd also like to have a set of custom links for each option, that differs from the text value. For example, option "Smartphones" but the link's URL is "apple.com". So how do I do this?

Comment: No problem, its very easy to tweak this code if you need to add/remove something.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var select = $('select');
    var value = select.val();
    select.replaceWith('<a href="'+ value.toLowerCase() +'.com">'+ value +'</a>');
});
```

See a [**demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yna0j66b/).

**EDIT:**

You can set a `data-something` attribute on element that you want, like:

```
<option data-something="apple">Smartphones</option>
```

Then in jQuery code:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var select = $('select');
    var value = select.val();
    var href = select.find(':selected').data('something') || value.toLowerCase();
    select.replaceWith('<a href="'+ href +'.com">'+ value +'</a>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/yna0j66b/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'd also like to have a set of custom links for each option, that differs from the text value. For example, option "Smartphones" but the link's URL is "apple.com". So how do I do this?